# How to run piCamera script in rc local?

Tags: raspicam, picamera

I have created a simple python script for the pi camera which works when run as is.

the file is located in ~/Destop/python

cameratest.py

```
import picamera
import time
camera = picamera.Picamera()
camera.capture('example.jpg')
```

I would like this to launch at startup/login, so I have done the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

where I added the following line of code before `exit 0`

```
python /home/me/Desktop/python/cameratest.py &
```

i then run `reboot`

No picture is taken and among the boot strings an error rc.local.... 'directory does not exist' pops up.
Can anyone advise me how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the full path to the `python` executable in rc.local, for example

```
/usr/bin/python /home/me/Desktop/python/cameratest.py &
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried that out. While it removed the error from the boot sequence, it still did not take a photo

Comment: Yes it did. It just stored the photo in the current working directory when rc.local gets started as a root process by systemd. It could be in /etc.

Comment: @Dougie you are right, it did take the photo. But for some reason it was in the root directory ( `/example.jpg`) . My understanding was that the jpg would be saved in the directory python called it from, hence using the full path name?

Comment: Without the full path the system did not know where to find the `python` executable (hence the error message) and could not execute the script (hence no saved picture). With the full path, the script was executed and (as Dougie said) the picture was saved in the current working directory of user executing the command (root). Change the python script if you want the picture to be saved in another directory.

Comment: @yesno thank you, I marked your answer as approved since it solved the issue. I added `import os` and then `os.chdir("/home/me/Desktop")` to test out choosing the save location which worked. Do you recommend this being the best way to go about this or have any advice if i should go about this differently?

Comment: My knowledge of Python scripting language is practically zero, so I wouldn't know except maybe replacing 'example.jpg' in the script with '/home/me/example.jpg'.

Comment: To clarify, probably you don't need to change more than just using camera.capture('/home/me/Desktop/image.jpg') instead of camera.capture('example.jpg') where `me` is your user name.